# LibGDX keeps giving me this error: "ERROR BAD LOGIC GAMES", how do I fix this?

Tags: java, libgdx, intellij-15

trying to get libgdx working on intellJ, but I keep getting this error, with an image that says bad logic games. I have already assign the working directory to the core/assets folder, but I am completely lost on what to do.

11:09:44 AM: Executing task 'DesktopLauncher.main()'...

> Task :core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :core:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :desktop:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :desktop:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :desktop:classes UP-TO-DATE

> Task :desktop:DesktopLauncher.main()
> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
> WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil$3 (file:/C:/Users/SKIKK/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.lwjgl.lwjgl/lwjgl/2.9.3/3df168ac74e4a8c96562cdff24ad352e255bf89c/lwjgl-2.9.3.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
> WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil$3
> WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
> WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Comment: That’s a warning, not an error. Is it crashing?

Answer (score 11):

This can happen if your system's Java version is incompatible with LWJGL2. libGDX began adding support for the LWJGL3 backend at least five years ago, but some setup guides and tutorials out there still have you set up a project with LWJGL2--even the official setup tool provided by libGDX creates a project with LWJGL2 as the backend.

Depending on your graphic needs, you may be fine just ignoring the error, and your program should still run on most systems. But it's recommended to switch to LWJGL3, because that is what the developers of libGDX continue to support.

To switch to the LWJGL3 backend, in your core projects dependencies, change:

```
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
```

to

```
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl3:$gdxVersion"
```

A [recently created issue](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/6426) on the libGDX issue tracker happens to give a little context on the warning you are seeing and the reasons why, if you're curious about the current state of the warning.

Comment: I had the same warnings, changed `lwjgl` to `lwjgl3` as you said, tried to run and got error:  `Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package org.lwjgl is sealed`. How can I solve it?

Comment: Hmm, that has come up before in [this instance](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/3673#issuecomment-167665255), you may be able to use the same solution in the next comment there: `replace LwjglApplicationConfiguration and LwjglApplication with Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration and Lwjgl3Application everywhere in your desktop launcher`